# OPL-Cplex saving the data view to Excel

Tags: cplex, opl

How do you export the "data view" to an excel spreadsheet in the style opl cplex shows you?

For example see screenshot. after clicking the icon marked with the red box you open the tab (green box). I want to save the green box into an excel spreadsheet in the style given by opl.
Is there a possibility? And if yes how do I do it?
I tried the sheetwrite command but i would loose the formatting.

Thanks a lot!

[image: data_view]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to copy the contents to the clipboard using Ctrl+C, or right-click and select the menu item.
You can then paste into Excel or a text editor.
You will lose the colors though.